# How to change source translation in yii2 in lajax/translatemanager module

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-module

I installed [this translate manager](https://github.com/lajax/yii2-translate-manager) on my Yii 2 Advanced application and I'm trying to translate source variant.

Imagine that I have 2 languages - English and German. In my code I have `Yii::t('frontend', 'Hello')`. And I translated it to German like 'Guten morgen' and it works (word 'Hello' changes depending on the current application language, and now - if it's `En` - it's 'Hello' and if it's `De` - it's 'Guten morgen').

But now I want to translate source word 'Hello' and `En` variant will be 'Hi'. I did this but word does not change. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii 2 does not translate source language to the same target language by default and it looks like this is the case (default language is `en-US` and you want to set `en`). To do this you need to set `forceTranslation` in configuration to `true` like:

```
'i18n' => [
    'translations' => [
        '*' => [
            'class' => 'yii\i18n\DbMessageSource',
            // ...
            'forceTranslation' => true,
        ],
    ],
],
```